# How to make a clock in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Stack Overflow and also new to Java. I am trying to make a clock in order to practice/reinforce my skills. Here is what my problem is:

I have made a class, TimeComponents, in which I have my source code for actually making the clock work. I am trying to figure out how to actually display my clock in my main class, TimeViewer. (Hopefully I am phrasing this correctly).

Here is the code:

```js
public class TimeComponents {
 
 public int seconds;
 public int minutes;
 public int hours;
 
 public TimeComponents(int initialHour, int initialMinutes, int initialSeconds){
  initialSeconds = 0;
  initialMinutes = 0;
  initialHour = 0;
  
 }
 public void Tick(){
  seconds = seconds ++;
  if(seconds == 60){
   minutes ++;
   seconds = 0;
   if(minutes == 60){
    hours ++;
    minutes = 0;
   }
  }
 }
 
 
  
}
```

And here is the main class that I want to use to print my clock:

```js
public class TimeViewer {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 }

}
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your main method is empty, what are you expecting to happen in an empty main method?

Comment: “make a clock” doesn’t tell us much.  Did you want to print it on the console?  Did you want it to be in a window?  If the latter, is it digital (`03:00`) or analog ()? If the former, did you intend to make it always print on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what your question actually is, but this line:

```
seconds = seconds ++;
```

will NOT increment seconds. I have tried it:

```
    int seconds = 0;
    seconds = seconds++;
    System.out.println(seconds);
```

prints 0.

The reason is that the ++ suffix applies the increment AFTER assigning the  value to the variable, so you lose the increment.

Try simply

```
seconds++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a toString function in your Time function. It makes a string with the 3 integers and you can print it in your main.

code TimeViewer:

```
public String toString(){
  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
}
```

code Main:

```
TimeComponent timecomponent  = new TimeComponent(0, 0, 0);
System.out.println(timecomponent);
```

I watched your code and it seems like your doing something weard in the constructor not linking with the class data (initial).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for specifically, but you asked for help generally, and I see a couple issues with your code that I can help with.

Your main method is empty, so nothing will happen when you run your code. Try to create an instance of TimeComponent in your main method, and call Tick() with it to see what happens.

In the constructor of your TimeComponents class, you have set your inputs "initialHour, initialMinutes, and initialSeconds" equal to zero. This does not declare your "minutes, seconds, and hours" variables, and will result in an error when you run your Tick() method. In your constructor, try setting each of these variables equal to your corresponding input variables to avoid this, like so:

```
    public TimeComponents(int initialHour, int initialMinutes, int initialSeconds){
            seconds = initialSeconds;
            minutes = initialMinutes;
            hours = initialHours;
    }
```

To increment using the ++ operator, it won't work unless you put the ++ right next to the name of the variable you want to increment, like so:

```
    hours++;
```

I hope this helped you solve your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you.
And sorry if you think there are some extra variables. They actually are used by me to implement a analog clock which I am trying right now.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Date_inner
{
    //on May 04 09:51:52 CDT 2009
    String date,time;
    int hh,mm,ss;
    void getData()
    {
            Date dat=new Date();
            String str=dat.toString();
            date=str.substring(7,10)+str.substring(3,7)+str.substring(23,28);
            hh=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(11,13));
            mm=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(14,16));
            ss=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(17,19));
            numtostring(hh,mm,ss);
    }
    void numtostring(int hh,int mm,int ss)
    {
         time=texttowords(hh)+"Hours "+texttowords(mm)+"Minutes "+texttowords(ss)+"Seconds ";
    }
    String texttowords(int num)
    {
        String arr[]={"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine ","Ten ","Eleven ","Twelve ","Thirteen ","Fourteen ","Fifteen ","Sixteen ","Seventeen ","Eighteen ","Nineteen ","Twenty ","Thirty ","Fourty ","Fifty "};
        if(num<=20)
            return arr[num-1];
        else if(num>20&&num<59)
        {
            return (arr[(num/10)+17]+arr[(num%10)-1]);
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
    void main()
    {
        getData();
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple clock.

```
package myclock;
public class Clock 
{
public int hours; 
public int minutes;
public int seconds;
public Clock()
{
  hours=12;
  minutes=0;
  seconds=0;
}
public Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
this.hours=hours;
this.minutes=minutes;
this.seconds=seconds;
}
public Clock(int seconds)
{
 this.seconds=seconds%60;
 hours=seconds/60;
 this.minutes=hours%60;//minutes
 this.hours=hours/60;//hours
}
public void setClock(int seconds)
{
this.seconds=seconds;
}
public int getHours()
{
return this.hours;
}
public int getMinutes()
{
return this.minutes;
}
public int getSeconds()
{
return this.seconds;
}
public void setHours(int hours)
{
  this.hours=hours;
}
public void setMinutes()
{
  this.minutes=minutes;
}
public void setSeconds()
{
  this.seconds=seconds;
}
public void tick()
{
this.seconds++;
}
public void tickDown()
{
this.seconds--;
}

public String toString()
{
return "("+String.format("%02d",this.hours)+":"+String.format("%02d",this.minutes)+":"+String.format("%02d",this.seconds)+")";
}

}
```

Then the implementation class will look like this.

```
package myclock;
public class MyClock 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Clock firstClock=new Clock(3602);//this is if you want to parse in seconds
    System.out.println(firstClock.toString()+"\n");
    Clock secondClock=new Clock(2,45,45);//this is if you want to parse in hours, minutes and seconds
    System.out.println(secondClock.toString());
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    firstClock.tick();
    System.out.println(firstClock.toString());
    }
}

}
```